# how to pass parameters through soap header in java

Tags: java

how to pass parameters through soap header in java

Comment: After my answer, do you realize how unclear and poorly formulated is your question?

Answer (score 2):

If using [SAAJ](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html), you can, with the following code:

```
SOAPHeader header = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();
header.addHeaderElement(yourElement);
```

If using JAX-WS RI, [see here](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/guide/SOAP_headers.html)
If using CXF, [see here](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIaddsoapheaderstotherequest%252Fresponse%253F).